# What does it mean setting "SET collapse_empty_table_version to false or true in netezza

Tags: netezza

can you please explain me what it does if we set 
"SET collapse_empty_table_version = false/true"
in netezza environment.

Answer (score 0):

This parameter controls the behavior when multiple table versions are created (e.g. when you alter a table to add a column) but no data was added to the table in one of the interim (i.e. not most recent) versions.

Each version of a table has its own data store. If this parameter is set to TRUE then the data store for interim version where no data was added are discarded, or collapsed.

For example:

> TABLE_A has some number of rows, and let's say we call its data store
>   TABLE_A.00 (the data stores are under the covers and have no names we
>   would normally reference).
>
> Then we alter TABLE_A to add a new column. This would have another
>   data store that we can call TABLE_A.01.
>
> Then we alter TABLE_A again to add another column before any rows are
>   added after our last alteration. This would have another data store
>   that we can call TABLE_A.02.
>
> At this point the data store TABLE_A.01 serves no purpose as it holds
>   no data, and can never receive any data.  If this parameter is set to
>   TRUE that data store will be reclaimed before a GROOM is performed.

Disclaimer: this parameter is something to fiddle with only when directed by IBM support as it is not publicly documented, and my description here is just my understanding of it, and is probably not complete or 100% accurate.